# ggplot geom_bar: Reversing Y axis but I would like to have bars coming from down-up not from top-down

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, geom-bar

The context of the data is that I am quantifying an assay where lower number is better. So I want lower number to be high up on the Y axis and my bars starting from bottom going up. However, when I use scale_Y_reverse, bars start from the top. How can I achieve what I want?

[image]

Thanks

Scale_Y_reverse makes bars start from top not from bottom. I want it to be from the bottom.

```
o <- data.frame('Time'=c(24,48),'Count'=c(20,40))

ggplot(o, aes(x=as.factor(Time),y=Count)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```

Comment: Hi, I would not recommend visualizing data like that. The plot you want is not very intuitive. How about transforming your data and try something like this to make low values be larger than high values: `-log(scale(o$Count, center = 0.5))`. Just an idea to build on from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot` is pretty strict about bars starting at 0, since that's almost universally a good idea. Unless 40 is a super special value for some reason, this plot is likely going to confuse a lot of people.

But I think you can do what you want by plotting:

```
ggplot(o, aes(x=as.factor(Time), y= 40 - Count)) + 
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = \(x) 40 - x, limits = c(0, 40))
```

[image]

Not recommended.

Comment: I know. I prefer not to. My PI asked for it. at least I can show him that this way is more confusing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @muratdus An alternative is to use `scale_y_reverse`, but with points instead of bars.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the coord_flip() function along with scale_y_reverse()

code:

```
library(ggplot2)

o <- data.frame('Time' = c(24, 48), 'Count' = c(20, 40))

o %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Time), y = Count)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: OP doesn't want their bars to start at 0.